# Unable to set Case OwnerId via the REST API

Tags: rest-api, case, queue

I'm adding a Case via the REST API, but the `OwnerId` field isn't being set.

I've also tried updating the Case record afterwards, and still the `OwnerId` isn't updated.

I am able to set/update the Case `OwnerId` via Apex and the Salesforce UI, with the same user.

---

RESP API request body (where `OwnerId` is the ID of the Queue to assign the Case to):

```
{
    "OwnerId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Subject": "Test Case",
    "Comments": "This is a test. Please ignore.",
    "Origin": "Web",
    "SuppliedEmail": "test@example.com"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "success": true,
    "errors": []
}
```

The following Apex, ran with the same user, works as expected:

```
Case c = new Case();
c.OwnerId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
c.Subject = 'Test Case';
c.Comments = 'This is a test. Please ignore.';
c.Origin = 'Web';
c.SuppliedEmail = 'test@example.com';
insert c;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is applicable for both Lead and Case.

This is a known issue, If your Org has active Lead assignment rule, you can't set the Owner properly with the normal REST API call. Please find the details in this Salesforce [Article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000390059&type=1).

You have to include the **Sforce-Auto-Assign** request header and set it to **false** in REST API requests to prevent assignment rules from running.

*You can do this with Composite API as below.*

Composite API URL : /services/data/v56.0/composite

Request Body:

```
{
  "allOrNone": false,
  "compositeRequest": [
    {
      "referenceId": "refLead",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/Lead",
      "body": {
        "FirstName": "Demo",
        "LastName": "Demo",
        "Company" : "ABC Inc.",
        "OwnerId": "00G...."
      },
      "httpHeaders": {
        "Sforce-Auto-Assign": "FALSE"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `Case or Lead` assignment rules

Comment: @cropredy - The issue exists for both Lead and Case Object. Thanks for the catch, I didn't  realize while posting the answer.