# Sforce-Auto-Assign header not having any apparent effect on assignment

Tags: api, case, rest, assignment-rules

I can't get the Sforce-Auto-Assign header to kick in when I'm creating a new Case:

```
resp = self.session.post(f'https://domain.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v60.0/sobjects/Case/',
    json=data,
    headers={
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.get_token()}',
        'Sforce-Auto-Assign': 'FALSE'
    })
```

Everything else is working in here, however I'm able to set neither the Owner nor an additional custom field, "Case_Assignee__c" to the User ID I provide. I'm currently having to immediately send in a PATCH to re-apply these two fields.

This post has had me wondering if I need to use the composite API entry point and have the header also  (?) in the composite payload for it to be used, but presumably this entry point is mostly just a sort of reverse proxy to send the parts to the more direct endpoint I'm already hitting?
[Unable to set Case OwnerId via the REST API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/396136/unable-to-set-case-ownerid-via-the-rest-api/396153#396153)

I'm *NOT* a SF developer, and access to config that I see talked about it not that easy for me, I can see that there appear to only be three AssignmentRule objects on the system, but they are all listed as Active: false. However there IS some automatic assignment happening from incoming emails etc. so I don't know what that Active value counts for, or what the rules actually do (getting off track here I presume, but I can't find any information in them other than that they exist, last update etc. where are the actual rules to be found?)

So from what I'm reading, there seems to be no documented reason that this header is being ignored / overridden, this header is apparently the exact solution to this sort of issue, so does this scenario point anyone to what might be happening?